# Topic Modelling: WordCloud For Every Topic in LDA model

Tags: python, nlp, lda, topic-modeling, word-cloud

Question: How can I create a Word Cloud for each topic that has been computed by the LDA model. I tried the following, but can't seem to work it out further to create a word cloud for each topic.

```
first_topic = lda.components_[0]
second_topic = lda.components_[1]
third_topic = lda.components_[2]
fourth_topic = lda.components_[3]

firstcloud = WordCloud(
                      background_color='black',
                      width=2500,
                      height=1800
                     ).generate(" ".join(first_topic))
plt.imshow(firstcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: For each component call the `WordCloud` constructor and prevent the output image from closing. You have done it for the first component or topic only. @Selena

Comment: @meti. I indeed only printed it for the first wordcloud, but I received the following error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.float64 found

Comment: The problem might be related to `lda.components_[0]`. I guess they are likely to be something except a list of strings. As you can see [here](https://github.com/meti-94/TextClassification/blob/main/SOF_test.ipynb) nothing is wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
def create_wordcloud(model, topic):
    text = {word: value for word, value in model.show_topic(topic)}
    wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=1000)
    wc.generate_from_frequencies(text)
    plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Topic" + " "+ str(topic))
    plt.show()
```

and then call this function as follow:

```
for i in range(1,num_topics):
    create_wordcloud(lda_model, topic=i)
```